# PHP - Foreach Loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

EDIT: Basically in the 2 foreach's there are variables called s1en, s1enkey, s1dl, s1dlkey, s1dlvalue. I need the '1' on those to increment each loop but how?

## s1en, s1enkey, s1dl, s1dlkey, s1dlvalue's PHP:

```
<?php

//Explode for Season 1 Downloads
if($r['s1downloads'] != '') { $s1dl = explode("~", $s1downloads); }

//Explode for Season 1 Episode Names
if($r['s1episodenames'] != '') { $s1en = explode("~", $s1episodenames); }

//Explode for Season 2 Episode Names
if($r['s2episodenames'] != '') { $s2en = explode("~", $s2episodenames); }

//Explode for Season 3 Episode Names
if($r['s3episodenames'] != '') { $s3en = explode("~", $s3episodenames); }

?>
```

#### The variable in explode() after the ~ is $r['s3episodenames'] which just has info gotten from database.

## Main Code Of PHP:

```
<?php

    $count = '1';

    for( $count=1; $count<101; $count++ ) {

        if($seasoncount = $count) {
            echo '<fieldset style="display: none;" id="season'.$count.'episodes" class="pure-group">';
            echo '<h2 style="color: #fff; display:inline-block">Episode</h2>';
            echo '<select style="display: inline-block; width: 50%;" id="selectseason'.$count.'episode" onload="javascript:season'.$count.'episodesChange()" onchange="javascript:season'.$count.'episodesChange()">';

            foreach ($s1en as $s1enkey ) {
                echo '<option>'.$s1enkey.'</option>';
            }

            echo '</select>';
            echo '<span id="s'.$count.'buttons">';

            foreach ($s1dl as $s1dlkey=>$s1dlvalue ) {
                echo '<button id="season'.$count.'episode'.($s1dlkey+1).'" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://crime.pw/tv/download/?url='.$s1dlvalue.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode '.($s1dlkey+1).'</button>';
            }

            echo '</span></fieldset>';
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: No use $i++ only if you have to increment or inside a for loop

Comment: Yes, I need to increment basically everything about season or s1 etc so season1 would be season2 next loop and s1 would be s2 next loop even the variables need to be changed like this :/

Comment: Why the downvotes xD

Comment: Add a counter outside your foreach loop. I don't downvote. Maybe people who are geniuses.

Comment: Aldrin when you say counter do you mean make like $i = '0'; or something? Like I know how to use i++ in loops but since I need to make the loop go a certain amount of times and increment a variables number I dont know what to do.

Comment: `$counter = 0` then inside your foreach loop `$counter++`

Comment: Yes I know that but how do I put the counter inside variables etc so that for example first loop its $x1 next loop its $x2 e.t.c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89549/discussion-between-john123-and-aldrin27).

Comment: I updated my question, Hopefully that will clear up all the downvotes for it being too simple or whatever.

Comment: sounds like you want array values, not code that writes code on the fly (and thus, the latter writing your variable names then executing them, huh?)

Answer (score 1):

### Found Answer!

```
${"s".$count."en"}
```

Simple guys, Thanks for the help!

Comment: boy, that variable name really flows off the tongue now doesn't it !

Comment: Try using portions of my code like the select tag, Seems a bit odd that this is even happening in the first place

Comment: Forgot to remove the option tags inside of my DB table storing episode names xD

Comment: arrays were built for this sort of thing. It is interesting shall I say. Imagine presenting that to peer review

Comment: Well yes I could use arrays but the structure of my site makes it impossible to do that and have it automated, Like my DB goes through searches for a id gotten by GET url request then it grabs some basic imdb tv show information and displays stuff like synopsis rating etc, It then gets episode names and season count and due to how this is all in one page I cant put it into a array as really its worse then straight from db into the loop id waste my time putting it into an array to do the same thing.

Comment: I guess I would have to see the whole thing in context. But, as I learned something, here are some appreciation points